# JavaScript (jquery) dropdowns for forms, that wouldn't require page reload (Rails app)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

We have three forms which are currently their own page but would work better as dropdowns I think. They each have only two fields and a submit button. I'd like it so the page doesn't reload after they click submit, they just keep using the site as they were.

One sample form:

```
<%= form_for(@app) do |f| %>
  <% if @app.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@app.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this app from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @app.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div>
    <%= f.text_field :url, :class => 'span4', :placeholder => "Paste the URL"  %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.text_field :description, :class => 'span4', :rows =>1, :placeholder 
      => "Give it a title" %>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:left">
      <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'd like to know the JavaScript code to place that code into on the page. I'm hoping there is a jquery plugin or similar for this - but I couldn't find anything searching jquery.com.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you need to direct your reading/search to ajax which allows you to post forms and get back results from posting those forms without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to write the code for you, but here are the steps:

1. Intercept the form's submit event. `$('#someForm').submit(function(e){});`
2. Cancel the default behavior. `e.preventDefault();`
3. Use AJAX to post the data to the form via JavaScript rather than a reload.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what the submit event or the default behavior here is though. I mean conceptually I understand but I can't identify where that is in the code. f.submit = submit event? How would I intercept that?

Comment: @wilfra - Added small examples to illustrate the concepts that I'm talking about.

Comment: @wilfra It may help to remember that the JavaScript is client-side (in the browser) and your Ruby on Rails code is server-side (on the server). Your server-side code is parsed to generate actual HTML, that HTML is passed back to the browser, and that's interpreted as your actual page. I'd guess that `<%= f.submit "Submit" %>` is converted to the HTML of a submit button, something like `<input type="submit" value="Submit">`. Clicking on that is what gives you your `submit` event.

Comment: Thanks for the help Justin and Anthony :)